# Print auto-value object as Java source code

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-generation, auto-value

I often find myself wanting to copy a living java object into my tests (in the source code). I doubt this is generally doable, but perhaps a `asJavaSourceCode()` method could be generated for all `@AutoValue` objects?

Here is some code to demonstrate what I want.

```
import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;


@AutoValue
public abstract class Person {

    public abstract String name();

    public abstract Integer age();

    public static Person create(String name, Integer age) {
        return new AutoValue_Person(name, age);
    }

    public String asJavaSourceCode() {
        // Can this code be automatically generated?
        return "Person.create(\"" + name() + "\"," + age() + ")";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Person.create("Jordan", 29));
        System.out.println(Person.create("Jordan", 29).asJavaSourceCode());
    }
}
```

When running this I get.

```
Person{name=Jordan, age=29}
Person.create("Jordan",29)
```

I would consider any of these a valid answer to this question:

- "Yes, here's a library *link*"
- "No, it doesn't exist yet"
- "Somebody else did something similar."
- "That is bad practice, don't do it, see Effective Java Book Item XYZ"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write a general-purpose `asJavaSourceCode()` using Java [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).  Start with `this.getClass()` which returns a [java.lang.Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object.  Get the class name with method `getName()`, `getCanonicalName()` or `getSimpleName()`.  Get the class's [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) descriptions with `getFields()`.  Each gives you a field name and its types, and methods to get its current value.

Since you're using `@AutoValue` you can assume a `create()` method on your class (which you can also discover with reflection), but I'm not sure you can reliably discover the order of the parameters to this method, because reflection [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) will give you the parameter types in the correct order, but not their names.  If `@AutoValue` doesn't order them deterministically, in a way you can reproduce when discovering the fields with reflection, then using an `@AutoValue` [builder](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/builders.md) instead of `create()` will allow you to write source that sets the fields by name.